# MySQL Understanding Connections

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have MySQL workbench installed so I can view live connections. When I have my browser closed and I am not viewing my web application, the connection is 4.

When I open my browser and go to my website on a page where a connection is required the connection stays at 4. If I open a second browser and do the same thing, the connection is still 4.

I am using PHP PDO to always connect to the same database. Why is my connection always staying at 4? I'm having trouble understanding this, In my mind expect this number to increase when I visit my website.

Comment: Even if web browser is closed - web server is running and it has connection pool, also - mysql workbench also creates connection(s)

Comment: @Lashane But should the connection count not increase when I visit my website?

Comment: Because web server/php used connection from connection pool without opening new one

Comment: @Lashane So with how I currently have things setup I do not need to worry about max connections?

Comment: definitely - yes, you always need to think about max connection settings from server side (mysql) and from client (php)